# Register-Login system

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x

I am trying to make a register-login system in Python 3, but when I check if the Email address already exists or not, it always says that it doesn't. I inserted an email and a password in the "users" table and when asked I used that same email address in this script but it still says that it doesn't exist. I have little to none experience in MySQL and thought that this may be a nice project to start with. Thank you.

```
import cymysql
from getpass import getpass


def get_user_info():
    while True:
        email = input("Input your Email address (max. 64 chars.): ")
        password = getpass("Input a password (max. 64 chars.): ")
        if len(email) < 64 and len(password) < 64: 
            return email, password


def check_account(cur, email, password):
    if(cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Email`='{email}' LIMIT 1")):
        print("exist")
    else:
        print("no exist")


def main():
    conn = cymysql.connect(
        host='192.168.0.109',
        user='root',
        passwd='',
        db='database'
    )
    cur = conn.cursor()
    email = ''
    password = ''
    email, password = get_user_info()
    check_account(cur, email, password)

    cur.close()
    conn.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Side Note: Doing f-strings and any other form of formatting makes your SQL vulnerable to sql injection. See [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) of better methods to pass parameters into your query (as an argument of the `execute` function).

Comment: Seems like you're using the cymysql module forked off pymysql. The relevant documentation seems to be https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>Disclaimer: I have yet to use `cymysql` – any code attached below is untested.</sup>

First, note that CyMySQL is a forked project of PyMySQL<sup>[[1]](https://github.com/nakagami/CyMySQL#whats-cymysql)</sup> so I will refer to documentation from PyMySQL.

From [`pymysql.cursors.Cursor.execute` documentation](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.execute):

> ```
> execute(query, args=None)
>     Execute a query
>     Parameters: 
>         query (str) – Query to execute.
>         args (tuple, list or dict) – parameters used with query. (optional)
>     Returns:        Number of affected rows
>     Return type:    int
> ```

The important thing to consider is the `execute` function returns: the **number of affected rows**. A `SELECT` query will not affect any rows, thus the function will return 0 and your function will print `no exist` reasonably.

Use [`fetchone`](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.fetchone) to check that at least one row was returned.

```
def check_account(cur, email, password):
    cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email`=%s LIMIT 1", (email,))
    row = cur.fetchone()
    if row:
        print("exist")
    else:
        print("no exist")
```

(I rewrote your `cur.execute` call in consideration of my [earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55315488/register-login-system#comment97358020_55315488).)